# Reload Table when View Controller has been navigated backwards to

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a table in one view controller and a "+" button to add to the table. The "+" button brings you to the next view controller, which contains a dialog and a "Save" button to add a new item to the table. upon clicking the save button i use the function

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

to bring it back to the previous viewController with the table. The table does not repopulate by itself and until i go back one more view controller and then reopen (which re-initializes it)

So i was thinking i could use this function

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

to reload it upon opening the viewController when i have navigated backwards to it.

Is there a function that is called when a viewController is viewed after clicking the back button on the next viewController?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: reload tableView in viewWillAppear

Comment: You can call [self.tableView reloadData]; in -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want `viewWillAppear`. UITableViewController's do some stuff already in `viewWillAppear` but you need to subclass in order to have it reload the table as well.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I don't think it does that by default because the viewController is not loading, I put the [self.tableView reloadData]; function in the viewWillAppear function and it works perfectly! thank you

Comment: Is your view controller a `UITableViewController`? Your question seems to imply that you are using a regular `UIViewController` that contains a `UITableView`. There is a difference.

Comment: Yes it is a UITableViewController